# PHImageManager requestAVAssetForVideo getting nil from second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, phasset

This code working properly for first time.

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc]init];
        options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
        options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic;
        options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:self.phAsset options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                AVURLAsset *urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
                NSURL *url = urlAsset.URL;
                completionHandler(url);
            });
        }];
```

From second time onwards, i am getting 'asset' and 'audioMix' as nil. 
'info' is as follows

```
{
    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 0;
    PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 0;
    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 20002;
}
```

> NOTE: after it happens unable to play the same video from 'photos'
>   application.

When i use above code,  am getting URL as below (for the first time only, second time onwards, url becomes nil)

> file:///Users/OD-1007/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66C92D6B-B528-40A4-A238-FC8C664E3774/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0011.mp4

When i use UIImagePickerController, it works perfectly, and the url is

> file:///Users/OD-1007/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/66C92D6B-B528-40A4-A238-FC8C664E3774/data/Containers/Data/Application/35B00947-04A4-4906-8E16-21FB4FF5A3F5/tmp/trim.74E42978-8B87-4C37-9B4C-8B70122A794F.MOV

Answer (score 7):

I think the issue with your request is that apple Photo is not syncing to iCloud. This make it that PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionCurrent doesn't work for some undocumented reason. if you switch version to:

```
PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal
```

it should work. That is what was causing the issue, in my case, and what fixed it for me.

```
PHVideoRequestOptions *options = [[PHVideoRequestOptions alloc]init];
options.version = PHVideoRequestOptionsVersionOriginal;
options.deliveryMode = PHVideoRequestOptionsDeliveryModeAutomatic;
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:self.phAsset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            AVURLAsset *urlAsset = (AVURLAsset*)asset;
            NSURL *url = urlAsset.URL;
            completionHandler(url);
        });
    }];
```

Edit: the request options was not passed in.

HTH,